# Postgres replication slot showing inactive

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using debezium postgres connector for change data capture. One of the connectors is streaming change events to Kafka but still the slot is showing as inactive in postgres table 'pg_replication_slots'.

Anyone knows the reason for this ?